# UIView set frame and set center not applied

Tags: ios, controls

I expect to change UIView (UISegmentedView to be more detailed) to change position but it's not applied:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 3 * 75, 50); // not working
    self.segmentedControl.center = self.view.center; // not working


    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:0]; // working
    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:1]; // working
    [self.segmentedControl setWidth:75 forSegmentAtIndex:2]; // working
}
```

One more result it that segment #3 can't be clicked though it's enabled and the right part of segment #2 is not clickable too which makes me think there is control active area width limitation. The view is created in UIViewController inheritor and xib.

Comment: Do you have Autolayout in your IB enabled?

Comment: Open your view in the Interface Builder. Now, on the utilities, show the file inspector. You will find a checkbox "Use Autolayout". Try unchecking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted this as an answer so you can check it as valid. For anyone having this problems, the first thing I would check is if autolayout is enabled on your view's interface builder.

Open your view in the Interface Builder. Now, on the utilities, show the file inspector. You will find a checkbox "Use Autolayout". If it's checked, try unchecking it to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: btw, how can i achieve the same goal (set segments width) not disabling auto layout?

Comment: You can achieve that by adding constraints to your view. After that you can link that constraints the same way you do with any other IBOutlet and then, change the constraint's constant value